# Bind to Static Resource with a Converter

Tags: c#, silverlight, datagrid, converters, staticresource

I have a `DataGrid` and two `StaticResource`.

I want to bind `RowStyle` of DataGrid to one of two StaticResources.

```
RowStyle="{StaticResource {Binding Status, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}}"
```

MyConverter returns StaticResource's Key.

But I get this error:

`Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **Static** Resource key is not a value that can be assigned **Dynamically**.  The name of the key needs to inline in the Xaml.

The correct approach is this:-

```
RowStyle="{Binding Status, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}"
```

Where the converter that is stored against the "MyConverter" key returns a `Style` object.  Note you could add a property of type `ResourceDictionary` to you converter and place you styles in that dictionary for you converter to lookup.

In fact I have already written a converter capable of this [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/codingbloke/archive/2010/06/09/yet-another-blog-about-ivalueconverter.aspx).

Comment: How can i fill `ResourceDictionary Items`? That is null.

Comment: @Navid: Start the Xaml in the blog post note that the items are included are inside `<ResourceDictionary></ResourceDictionary>` element.

Comment: OK TNX, That is working. Is it possible to use another `ResourceDictionary` e.g. a `ResourceDictionary` in `App.xaml`?

Comment: @Navid: Just move the converter to the App.xaml.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Another version of writing such a converter

public abstract class BaseConverter : MarkupExtension
{
    protected IServiceProvider ServiceProvider { get; set; }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        ServiceProvider = serviceProvider;
        return this;
    }    
}


public class StaticResourceConverter : BaseConverter, IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return new StaticResourceExtension(value).ProvideValue(ServiceProvider);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        //TODO - implement this for a two-way binding
        throw new NotImplementedException(); 
    }
}
```